# Show only results equal to current user id in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Gecko bundle that in the `index.html.twig` file it loops through and shows all geckos in the database, which is working great, no problem.

What i want to do however, is ONLY show geckos that have the same user id linked to them that's equal to the current user's id.

The index file is as follows:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <h1>Gecko list</h1>

    <table class="records_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Aquisitiondate</th>
                <th>Morph</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Genetics</th>
                <th>Bio</th>
                <th>Bred</th>
                <th>Hatchling</th>
                <th>Clutch</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ path('gecko_show', { 'name': entity.name }) }}">{{ entity.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
                <td>{% if entity.aquisitionDate %}{{ entity.aquisitionDate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif %}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.morph }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.sex }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.genetics }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.bio }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.bred }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.hatchling }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.clutch }}</td>
                <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('gecko_show', { 'name': entity.name }) }}">show</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('gecko_edit', { 'name': entity.name }) }}">edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

        <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('gecko_new') }}">
                Create a new entry
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

How do i go about limiting the view?

EDIT:

This is the Gecko controller:

```
<?php

namespace Breedr\GeckoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Breedr\GeckoBundle\Entity\Gecko;
use Breedr\GeckoBundle\Form\GeckoType;

/**
 * Gecko controller.
 *
 * @Route("/gecko")
 */
class GeckoController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Gecko entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="gecko")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new Gecko entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="gecko_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Gecko();
        $entity->setUser($this->getUser());
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('gecko_show', array('name' => $entity->getName())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Gecko entity.
     *
     * @param Gecko $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Gecko $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new GeckoType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('gecko_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Gecko entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="gecko_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Gecko();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Gecko entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{name}", name="gecko_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($name)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->findOneByName($name);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Gecko entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($name);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Gecko entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{name}/edit", name="gecko_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($name)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->findOneByName($name);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Gecko entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($name);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Gecko entity.
    *
    * @param Gecko $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Gecko $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new GeckoType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('gecko_update', array('name' => $entity->getName())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * Edits an existing Gecko entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{name}", name="gecko_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $name)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->findOneByName($name);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Gecko entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($name);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('gecko_edit', array('name' => $name)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a Gecko entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{name}", name="gecko_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $name)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($name);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->findOneByName($name);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Gecko entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('gecko'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Gecko entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($name)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('gecko_delete', array('name' => $name)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

This is from the `Gecko` entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Breedr\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="geckos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

Comment: Is this Gecko related to user with some way?

Comment: Just adding something @TomaszSkorupka

Comment: @TomaszSkorupka i've added the bit that controls the user id when adding a gecko to the database. So the info is there, i just need to limit the view to only show geckos with a `user_id` that matches the current user id. I'm using FOS user bundle

Comment: I posted the answer try it and give me feedback if it helps or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to get user before View, so we can get it by

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

Described here

> [Getting the user id from logged in user in FOSUserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911199/getting-the-user-id-from-logged-in-user-in-fosuserbundle)

Next step is to get data from repository by user object

By user object i preffer

```
$entities = $em
        ->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')
        ->findBy(array('user' => $user), array()
    );
```

I think it should work.

Comment: We can use "getUser()" of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller as it already implemeted to get user from security context

Comment: That's right @Evgeniy Kuzmin, that's the shortest way, I made an improvement :)

Comment: We should be thankful to @EvgeniyKuzmin too. He helped you too :)

Comment: collective intelligence :)

Answer (score 3):

```
class GeckoController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Gecko entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="gecko")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $entities = $em->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Gecko')->findBy('user' => $user->getId());

        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }
```